# Convert Map<String, List<Object>> to Map<String, List<String>> in java 1.8

Tags: java

I have a `Map<String, List<Object>>` , I would like to convert it to `Map<String, List<String>>` in java 8 .

In Java 1.7 I  was using a function to extract value from Map and then wrote another method declared empty List , used for loop to extract each element and then added to List Object in java 1.7

Any suggestions to do same in java 8  using lambda expressions

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are these objects? How do you intend to convert them to strings?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = map.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> Map.entry(e.getKey(),
                e.getValue().stream()
                        .map(o -> (String) o) //or Object::toString depending on the object
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

`Map.entry` is from Java 9, you can use `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` if you are on Java 8.